# How to serialize empty ImageField to JsonResponse?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, model

I have a model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name='Title', default='Default title')
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Photo',upload_to='media/',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am trying to serialize this model object to JSON response for the  frontend. This is my test view:

```
from app.models import Item
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    item_object = Item.objects.first()
    to_json = model_to_dict(item_object)
    return JsonResponse(to_json)
```

When i created Item object without photo field (from django shell without downloading real file, this field isn't nessesary), JsonResponse throws TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

```
[16/Nov/2016 13:51:15] "GET /items/?item_id=9&shop_id=4 HTTP/1.1" 500 129160
Internal Server Error: /items/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lamberk/python/picasel/rc_cross_upsell/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/lamberk/python/picasel/rc_cross_upsell/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/lamberk/python/picasel/rc_cross_upsell/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/lamberk/python/picasel/rc_cross_upsell/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lamberk/python/picasel/rc_cross_upsell/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lamberk/python/picasel/rc_cross_upsell/CrossUpsell/apps/items/views.py", line 54, in get
    'up_sells': up_sells,
  File "/home/lamberk/python/picasel/rc_cross_upsell/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 520, in __init__
    data = json.dumps(data, cls=encoder, **json_dumps_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/lamberk/python/picasel/rc_cross_upsell/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 118, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <ImageFieldFile: None> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: That code you have posted is incomplete/and or does not correspond to the  stacktrace you have posted.

Comment: and what do you mean by "But if i haven't download photo yet"

Comment: @e4c5 yeah, sorry. I edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using custom JSON encoder, something along those lines:

```
class CustomEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, ImageFieldFile):
            # Do whatever appropriate for your case, like returning None
        return super(CustomEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

And use it like this:

```
return JsonResponse(to_json, encoder=CustomEncoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write item serializer and use it instead of model_to_dict()

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Or if you want to use model_to_dict, you can put your code in if else block.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    item_object = Item.objects.first()
    if item_object:
        to_json = model_to_dict(item_object)
        return JsonResponse(to_json)
```

Comment: Is it reasonable to use rest_framework package only for this feature?

Moreover, the problem is not in empty object. It is in empty photo `ImageField` in item object.

Comment: @K.Valentin it is unreasonable if you don't use ajax requests in your app much. However, if the number of such ajax endpoints starts to grow, or you ever decide to make some sort of REST API, you should consider it at some moment.